# Facebook Graph API - Status updates

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently using the Graph API to retrieve the News Feed for a user. However, some Posts of type "update" do not return any info on the original post e.g. in the result extract posted below, the story is "Joubert Nel commented on a link", but there is no info included as to what the link is, or the picture that goes with it. How can I obtain this info please?

```
actions =             (
                            {
                link = "https://www.facebook.com/637106301/posts/520940825396";
                name = Comment;
            }
        );
        comments =             {
            data =                 (
                                    {
                    "can_remove" = 0;
                    "created_time" = "2014-03-15T13:06:43+0000";
                    from =                         {
                        id = 100000194244146;
                        name = "Laurie Edwards";
                    };
                    id = "520940825396_133907";
                    "like_count" = 2;
                    message = "Or you could just come home for a while!";
                    "user_likes" = 0;
                },

            );
            paging =                 {
                cursors =                     {
                    after = "MTI=";
                    before = "MQ==";
                };
            };
        };
        "created_time" = "2014-03-15T14:41:56+0000";
        from =             {
            id = 637106301;
            name = "Joubert Nel";
        };
        id = "637106301_520940825396";
        likes =             {
            data =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 214500098;
                    name = "Samuel Freilich";
                },
                                    {
            );
            paging =                 {
                cursors =                     {
                    after = "OTUwMTE2OA==";
                    before = MjE0NTAwMDk4;
                };
            };
        };
        privacy =             {
            value = "";
        };
        story = "Joubert Nel commented on a link.";
        "story_tags" =             {
            0 =                 (
                                    {
                    id = 637106301;
                    length = 11;
                    name = "Joubert Nel";
                    offset = 0;
                    type = user;
                }
            );
        };
        type = status;
        "updated_time" = "2014-03-15T14:41:56+0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

is the link posted by Joubert? or using app you have permission. sounds like you don't have permission to post(link) but u have permission to Joubert activities

Comment: He did not post it, he just commented on it. In facebook's app I can see the link details and image, so I do not suspect it to be a persmissions issue.

Comment: what do you mean facebook app? app you have created in developer.facebook.com or facebook own app?